# TFS configuration with git repository shared across multiple projects

Tags: git, tfs

I am trying out TFS for our projects and I have found an apparent incompatibility with our current development process.

The issue is, that we have one product repository, which contains many visual studio projects (309, not counting the C++ ones). Many of these projects are shared across multiple VS solutions (each solution represents a subsystem).

I would like to stick to this repository configuration, but use a separate TFS project for each of the subsystems, so that we could have separate sprints for each subsystem.

There are two ways I see to configure this:
1. Shared TFS Git repository for multiple TFS projects
2. Use an external Git repository and configure each of the TFS projects to use the same external repository.

I have searched, but I am unable to find whether either of these ways is possible.

Do you know whether this is an achievable goal? Is there any other approach I should try to satisfy our needs?

Thank you for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can and should do all of that within a single Team Project.

If you create a single Team Project with Git as the SCM you can create a Git repo for each of the Subsystems.

You can then create Teams for each of the projects/project groupings/teams that you want to monitor. All of your work items can be kept separate for each subsytem using Area Path while giving you rollup capability accross all of them .

http://nakedalm.com/modelling-teams-in-team-foundation-server-2013/

In this post I just described the gerneral modeling available with the team capability.

http://nakedalm.com/creating-nested-teams-visual-studio-alm/

And here I show an example implementation. Imagine if each of the sub teams are sub systems.

Each subsystem can have its own iterations, but it really depends on the teams that you have. If you have 4 teams that have the sub systems decided up you should probably only have 4 teams, but they own many Areas (Subsystems).

You could also decide to decide to use Area Path for team and a tag for subsystem. Then you can decide work to team backlogs independently of subsystem.

Or you could use Area Path for SubSystem hierarchy and use Team Field to denote team.

My point is that within a single Team Project you get the flexibility to shape and reshape your backlogs, work, code, and people. In multiple team projects you are constrained by the Team Project boundary.